# How can I implement a horizontal scroll bar that sits at the bottom of the current view?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have a main container. Inside this container I have a div which spans a height which fits into the main container and needs to remain that way. It also has a width wider than the main container, with an overflow for the horizontal scroll bar.

The issue I'm having:
1. Rather than expecting the user to scroll to the bottom of the page and then use the horizontal scroll bar, I would like the horizontal scroll bar to be fixed to the bottom of the view (not the div)

1. On load, I would like the horizontal scroll bar to be present at the bottom of the users screen. As the user scrolls down, the horizontal scroll bar moves down the page with it until reaching the bottom where it'll sit at the bottom of the div (rather than the window)

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/LBIsf

Comment: if it has to remain all time on bottom screen, then use position:fixed;+bottom:0;+left:0;+right:0; and eventually z-index if needed

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus - I've updated my post with a reference to another which I have just found. Having a fixed div doesn't resolve the issue unfortunately. I need to page to scroll vertically in the normal fashion through the overall browser scrollbar, and the main div scroll bar. However, I would like the horiztonal scrollbar to sit at the bottom of the window view (not the div) until the user has scrolled to the very bottom, where the horizontal scroll will go back to its normal position at the bottom of the div.

Comment: I'm a bit confused actually, i read again and do not really understand how it is suppose to work. do you have a sketch and or a jsfiddle/codepen to check it out ?

Comment: Hi @GCyrillus - No problem, I probably haven't explained too well! =) I have quickly sketched up an example here: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/LBIsf or here http://codepen.io/seraphzz/full/LBIsf (for the full browser view) as you can see, i need to scroll to the bottom of the page to use the horizontal scroll. What I would ideally like would be for the horizontal scroll to always be visible at the bottom of the view whilst the user uses the vertical browser scroll to go down.

Comment: it makes it clear, unfortunatelly, CSS won'nt achive this, you need js to have inside content auto-scrolling width the main page and check both lenght to adapt smaller to longtest. (page + its content with taht content inside a box 100% heighth of screen)

Comment: Thought as much. Would you be so kind to help with the js please? No worries if not of course! I've tried working out the window height (what's visible to the user, then modifying the divs height to match, but, that obviously didn't work.

Comment: why not, it has to do with height, offsetheight and scrollheight. i'll post something, but right now i have to go, i'll be offline about 8 hours.

Comment: @GCyrillus - No worries, that's fantastic. I'll research into it in the meantime. Again, I appreciate your time and assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what i'm coming up.

```
    function startit() {
      // let's sort out what we need
          /* window's height */
        var bodysHeight     = document.body.offsetHeight;
           /* window's width */
        var bodysWidth     = document.body.offsetWidth;
          /* table container */
        var myTable         = document.getElementById('tablefixed');
          /* table container's height */
        var myTableHeight   = myTable.offsetHeight;
          /* content */
        var mycontent =document.getElementById('gotainer');  
          /* let's see about layout */
        var col1W    = 250;
        var myTableW = 400;

          // then change values needed
        if (bodysHeight < myTableHeight) 

               { /* if body's heighht less than table */
                  mycontent.style.height = myTableHeight+ 20 +'px';
                  window.onscroll = function() {scrollit();    }
               }
        else 
               {
                  myTable.style.height =  bodysHeight+'px';
               }

         /* we watch now col1 & col2 to remain in screen en cover all heigth */
        var mycol1 = document.getElementById('col1');
        var mycol2  =document.getElementById('content');
          /* set it not too wide */
        mycol2.style.width = bodysWidth - col1W - myTableW -50 +'px';
          /* set here height if CSS does not  */
        //mycol1.style.height= mycontent.offsetHeight+'px';
        //mycol2.style.height= mycontent.offsetHeight+'px';
    }

    function scrollit() {
    function scrollit() {
if(!window.pageYOffset) {
     var pageScroll = document.getElementById('scrolling').scrollTop;  
     }

else {
    var pageScroll = window.pageYOffset;
      }
    var mycontent =document.getElementById('gotainer');
    var table = document.getElementById('tablefixed');
    table.style.margin='-'+pageScroll+'px 0  0';
} 
        var mycontent =document.getElementById('gotainer');
        var table = document.getElementById('tablefixed');
        table.style.margin='-'+pageScroll+'px 0  0';
    }


    window.onload     = startit ;
    window.onresize   = startit;
    window.onscroll   = scrollit;
```

Notice:(if you did not) - it's rookie coding.
My codepen http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/CHfAb It works with my firefox too.

Comment: It did not work first time with FF. .scrollTop turns to be .pageYoffset for FF in standard mode .It catches scrollTop from HTML, in quirksmode  it will catch it from body.

Comment: Thanks, for the response, i'll have to try and give it a go to get my head around it. Thank you for taking the time to do it. I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: how did it go ? i crossed a page that might be usefull too for your issue: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html

Comment: Hey - I ended up using a plugin which implemented it. I appreciate all your help with looking into it.

Comment: great !, is there infos or link you could share about this plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy-to-use solution to have a custom scrollbars compatble with destkop, tablet and phone devices.

It supports DIVs, IFrames, textarea, and document page (body) scrollbars.

for horizontal or vertical access this will help full for you

go to...

http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/